# how to see more infomation in ndk-gdb when the program breakdown

Tags: android, debugging, stack, android-ndk

I use eclipse and ndk-gdb to debug my AndroidNDK program,but i find a problem,the ndk-gdb tools seems do not have the function of "saving the stack" when the program breakdown,i cannot find detail infomation from the ndk-gdb,it does not point which function,which class and which line,just give the info like this:*Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.0xafd0cda4 in memcpy ()
   from D:/android/ndk/samples/mango_d/obj/local/armeabi/libc.so*

so , i was wondering if there is a way to see more infomation(the last sentence the program called or others) when the program breakdown,thank you fist

Answer (score 0):

You could try utilize the ndk-stack program, consult to the doc in the ndk, docs/NDK-STACK.html

If you compile the c source by

```
ndk-build NDK_DEBUG=1 APP_OPTIM=debug
```

you should be able to call something similar like this one

```
adb -s %TARGET_INSTALL% logcat DEBUG:I | ndk-stack -sym ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a
```

that one will give you the source code and line stack trace for the seg-fault.